# Using noscript to optimize for SEO

Tags: html, ajax, seo

I have news portal that loads posts using ajax, to get better user experience. Web crawlers don't see links and texts generated by javascript, so I read about using **noscript** tags for crawlers. In *noscript* section I render title, subtitle, description and link to a post, by using headers tags in proper way (in my php code).
Many SEO analyzer sites now see that content, but I dont know about real crawlers like Google and others.
Is his this a good way to make my content visible to crawlers? I see it is easy...

Comment: Stupid question: If you already load the posts once to display them in the `noscript`-tag, why load it again via AJAX? Why don't you just put the posts outside the noscript tag, so everyone can see it and save the clients one AJAX request?

Comment: All humans as well as all the major bots now run scripts. Google even has methodology for making sure your Ajax content is fully crawlable: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ So what bot are you concerned with finding your data? None of the rest really matter unless you wanna allow exploit scanners, comment spammers, content scrapers, and SEO bots triggered by your competition ;) And the humans with JS disabled is a moot point nowadays. Literally no one would do such a silly thing -- you cant run 99.9% of the web without JS.

Comment: Im sorry, i am relatively new to web programming, I hardly managed a site  to work. When I finished programming, I got tasks to optimize site for SEO (Google is main crawler I want to optimize for).

I think I was testing via "Fetch as Google", and i think the content came from AJAX call did not process by Google, so i put noscript, just to make content "visible".

I am searching the way to set basic SEO optimization because i dont want big changes to site.

Here is the site: www.balkanreporter.rs

Comment: https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't want to use noscript as crawlers will ignore that. By looking at the clean cache of your page: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.balkanreporter.rs/&hl=en&strip=1 I can see text is visible on your page so you should be good to go. One thing to note is to update your anchor text to wrap around useful words like Manifestacije u Srbiji instead of Pročitajte.

Save this code as a bookmarklet to quickly access your page's clean text cache. On any webpage, click this bookmarklet to be taken to the clean-cache. You might want to adjust which Google search property it checks though.

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:'+document.URL+'&hl=en&strip=1')})();
```

Comment: Thank you David! But the content in the cache is rendered though noscript, I already added noscript to page.

Comment: https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

The `<noscript>` tag has been spammed and abused by blackhats trying to gain search engine rankings.     Because of this history, Google now treats sites that use the tags with suspicion.

Now [Google warns against using noscript tags](https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/022411.html).